# Will SharePoint Designer 2007 work with Office 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-2016

If I currently use SharePoint 2007, but have Office 2016 installed on my computer, will SharePoint Designer 2007 work on my computer, or will I have issues?  I am not upgrading to SharePoint 2016 until later this year (2017), or early next year(2018).

Comment: I have Office 2016 installed and use both SP Designer 2007 and SP Designer 2013 with no issues.

Comment: On a side note, do note that SharePoint Designer 2007 is approaching the end of its support by Microsoft, which is dated to be 10/10/2017.

Answer (score 1):

SP Designer 2013 is the SP recommended tool for now.  I'm using it for SP 2013 and SP Online, no issues.